The package "crypto" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node
On trying to use crypto module from TypeScript there is an error:

The package "crypto" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.

I am not sure how to use "platform: 'node'"
code.ts:
import * as crypto from "crypto";

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}

package.json:
{
  "name": "tests",
  "version": "0.0.1-dev",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/cypress": "^1.1.3",
    "cypress": "^13.7.1",
    "cypress-xpath": "^2.0.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.20.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^20.0.3"
  }
}


Does this answer your question? Where do I put "platform: 'node'" in an Angular 17 app running on node 20? - Note this is only relevant if you are really building for node. If you are building for the browser, using crypto is wrong, as that package only exists within node!
